# AIML: List of choices is not finding matching pattern

Tags: xml, pattern-matching, aiml

I am attempting to build the example file that is listed here.  https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/BVA9/Sample.aiml+file

I was able to write out the file (I think correctly) here.
https://gist.github.com/pemby/679571f9eb9a413faa72811bbbe85621

Running the file I think it is failing the first pattern match.

```
<category>
<pattern>CMP</pattern>
<template>
    Which password do you want to change?<br/>
    1) Lotus password.<br/>
    2) Sgate password. <br/>
    3) NT/PC password.<br/>
    Enter yoour choice-1/2/3.
</template>
```

Then fails here...

```
<category>
    <pattern>1</pattern>
    <that>* Enter your choice-1/2/3.</that>
    <template>
    <think>
    <set name="option1">1</set>
    </think>
    <srai>ACMP</srai>  
    </template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo of "yoour" in your first category. Also you need to add </category> at the end of your first category. You are checking for the wrong value of <that> in your second category (the documentation you are learning from is incorrect). I've posted the correct and working version of your code.

```
<category>
    <pattern>CMP</pattern>
    <template>
        Which password do you want to change?<br/>
        1) Lotus password.<br/>
        2) Sgate password. <br/>
        3) NT/PC password.<br/>
        Enter your choice-1/2/3.
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>1</pattern>
    <that>ENTER YOUR CHOICE *</that>
    <template>
        <think>
            <set name="option1">1</set>
        </think>
        <srai>ACMP</srai>  
    </template>
</category>
```